# splitter aggregator pattern with microservices

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-integration, microservices

I need to create a system that does the following:

1. receive uploaded file via http multipart request - and return 200 ok upon success
2. passing the uploaded file to multiple external services
3. wait to all results from external services , and calculating the final response
4. return the response to a activemq as a publisher

there are some constraints:

1. those external services are services of 3rd party companies, so some of them might be using different apis/protocols.
2. i want to be able to plug & unplug 3rd party vendors at runtime.
3. be able to support scaling of multiple instances from the same vendor to enhance performance

my thought process has brought me so far:

1. using spring-integration or apache camel as a splitter-aggregator pattern module
2. each 3-rd party vendor will be an independent spring boot application
3. the entry point to the the application will be another spring boot application

i have some open questions

1. i still don't know what is the best way to pass the files between the different services? by message queue? just proxy the request to multiple microservices?
2. how to support plug & unplug at run time?

any pointers or help will be very helpful!

Comment: Have you thought of websockets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitely looks like [Scatter-Gather](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#scatter-gather).

You have a `PublishSubscribeChannel` and can add and remove subscribers for it at run time.

Regarding `plug & unplug` question you can take a look into recent [`IntegrationContext`](https://spring.io/blog/2016/09/27/java-dsl-for-spring-integration-1-2-release-candidate-1-is-available) feature in the Spring Integration Java DSL 1.2.